# Suppose that A,B,C, and D are sets. Prove $(A-B)\times(C-D) = (A\times C) - [(A\times D) \cup (B\times C)]$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Suppose that A,B,C, and D are sets. Prove $(A-B)\times(C-D) = (A\times C) - [(A\times D) \cup (B\times C)]$

This is what I have done so far:

Proof:

We are trying to prove $(A-B)\times(C-D) = (A\times C) - [(A\times D) \cup (B\times C)]$, which is equivalent to proving $[(x,y)∈(A-B)\times(C-D)] ⟺ [(x,y)∈(A\times C) - [(A\times D)\cup(B\times C)]]$ by definition of a set product.

Assume $(x,y)∈(A-B)\times(C-D)$.

⟹ $x∈(A-B)$ and $y∈(C-D)$

⟹ $x∈A\cap B^\complement$ and $y∈C\cap D^\complement$

⟹ $x∈A$ and $x∈B^\complement$ and $x∈C$ and $x∈D^\complement$

⟹ $(x,y)∈ A\times C$ and $x∈B^\complement$ and $x∈D^\complement$

But now I'm stuck. I don't know how to introduce the extra $A^C$ and $C^C$ terms necessary for showing the implication.

Comment: Don't Shout!!!!

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Your questions will be a lot easier to read (and so you will get more help) if you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've gotten yourself a little tangled up.  First, when you want to show that two sets are equal, it often easiest to show that each is a subset of the other.  It's also easier if you try to figure out what the statements mean, instead of looking for formal manipulations that transform one expression to another.  For example, at one point, you switched the $y$ in your calculations to $x$, and the statements stopped making sense.

To prove $$(A\setminus B)\times(C\setminus D)\subseteq  (A\times C)\setminus[A\times D \cup B\times C] $$ take $(x,y)\in (A\setminus B)\times(C\setminus D),$ so that $x\in A, x\notin B, y\in C, y\notin D. $
Certainly, $(x,y)\in A\times C$ so we only have to prove that $(x,y)\notin A\times D$ and $(x,y)\notin B\times C$. The first of these statements is true because $y\notin D$.  The second in true because $x\notin B$.

See if you can use the same technique to prove the reverse implication.

Answer (score 0):

If you know already some Boolean algebra you can prove the claim quite easily as follows:

- For any set $X$ let $x$ be the Boolean variable with $x = 1 (True)$ if and only if $x \in X$.
- I will use "$a+b$" for "$a$ or $b$" and "$ab$" for "$a$ and $b$", "$a'$" for "not $a$", $0 = False$, $1 = True$ etc.

So, you only need to show the logical equivalence

$$ab'cd' = ac(ad + bc)'$$

Working from right to left you get using standard Boolean operations
\begin{eqnarray*} ac(ad + bc)'
& \stackrel{DeMorgan}{=} & ac((a'+d')(b'+c'))\\
& = & ac(a'b'+a'c' + b'd' + c'd')\\
& \stackrel{xx'=0}{=} & 0 + 0 + acb'd' + 0 \\
& = & ab'cd'
\end{eqnarray*}
Done.